# Reading package drawings (from TI)

Tags: packages

I am wwondering what a certain parts of the drawing mean. For example in the picture below, what mens 24x in front of the some dimensions? In the down-right corner, what are numbers 0.1 and 0.05 for and M within the circle?

[image: A part of the drawing]

Comment: How many pins does that package have?

Comment: You might get better answers if you looked at some of your questions and formally accepted some more answers. It's a small price to pay for getting good info from the guys here.

Comment: I must admitt I have never looked how this kind of information sharing works, but I accept your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Feature Control Frame** (rectangular box) contain the geometric characteristics symbol, and the form, runout or location tolerance. You can find more information on this [PDF](https://engineering.pages.tcnj.edu/files/2012/02/dimensioning_and_tolerancing.pdf). The M within a circle stand for [Maximum Material Condition (MMC)](http://www.gdandtbasics.com/maximum-material-condition/)

"24x" means that the description is true for the 24 pins of the part.